# Coverting int to string and checking postion to see if it matches a value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do some simple Python, which allows the user to enter a 6 digit number into the command line; my code then needs to check the values of the first and sixth digit of the number entered.

The value entered is stored in a variable named `uinumber`, I then check using an `if` statement to check if the values at these locations match. As shown below:

```
 if uinumber[1] == 5 and uinumber[6] == 0:
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. I have also tried converting the number entered to a string and then doing the check as show below, but this causes the same issue.

```
 uinumber_string = str(uinumber)
  if uinumber_string[1] == 5 and uinumber[6] == 0:
```

This seems to cause the same issue; what is the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about needing to cast the inputted number to a string, but you then need to *compare* it to a string as well.

Additionally, since you mentioned a 6-digit number, the correct indices are probably `[0]` and `[5]` and not `[1]` and `[6]`, as sequences in Python (and most other programming languages) are zero-indexed.

And on one last note, you wrote `uinumber[6]` by accident instead of `uinumber_string[6]`.

```
uinumber_string = str(uinumber)
if uinumber_string[0] == "5" and uinumber_string[5] == "0":
    # Do something
```

Comment: ah right, same as Java then, like array elements! This would make sense.